# Syntax Error: Non-declaration statement outside function body

Tags: function, go, closures

The function `makeEvenGenerator` is supposed to return a function that generates even numbers in a sequential manner:

```
package main 
import "fmt"
func makeEvenGenerator() func() uint {
    i := uint(0)
    return func() (ret uint) {
        ret = i
        i += 2
        return
    }
}func main() {
    nextEven := makeEvenGenerator()
    fmt.Println(nextEven()) // 0
    fmt.Println(nextEven()) // 2
    fmt.Println(nextEven()) // 4
}
```

When I run it, I get the error `syntax error: unexpected func, expecting semicolon or newline` and `Non-declaration statement outside function body`.

The code is taken verbatim from *An Introduction to Programming in Go* by Caleb Doxsey. I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a newline between the "}" at the end of the `makeEvenGenerator` and the "func" in `main`.

I fixed the error and posted the code to the [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/PgK3jH90B8).

Answer (score 5):

There are rules about semicolons.

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Semicolons](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Semicolons)
>
> The formal grammar uses semicolons ";" as terminators in a number of
>   productions. Go programs may omit most of these semicolons using the
>   following two rules:
>
> 1. When the input is broken into tokens, a semicolon is automatically inserted into the token stream at the end of a non-blank line if the
>      line's final token is
>          an identifier
>          an integer, floating-point, imaginary, rune, or string literal
>          one of the keywords break, continue, fallthrough, or return
>          one of the operators and delimiters ++, --, ), ], or }
> 2. To allow complex statements to occupy a single line, a semicolon may be omitted before a closing ")" or "}".

The error is here,

```
}func main() {
```

Write,

```
}
func main() {
```

Answer (score 4):

You were missing a new line between `}` at the end of `makeEvenGenerator` and `func main`.

Also an alternative approach for that pattern is to use a channel not return a function:

```
func evenGenerator() <-chan uint {
    ch := make(chan uint)
    go func() {
        i := uint(0)
        for {
            ch <- i
            i += 2
        }
    }()
    return ch
}

func main() {
    evens := evenGenerator()
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-evens)
    }
}
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/1HklcNfI-w)</kbd>

Comment: It is an alternative approach, not "the usual approach." For example, in this case, using a channel has a one hundredfold performance penalty, 3481 ns/op versus 34.4 ns/op.

Comment: @peterSO Good point, updated. btw channel speeds improved drastically in 1.4, 211ns vs 2.23ns on tip.